# What is the best solution to generate with PHP Doc/docx and PDF files from the same source?

Tags: php, pdf, docx, phpdocx

What do you see as best solution to generate with PHP DOC/DOCX files and PDF files with the same source code or template?

We have been using the document generate from paggard for about 10 years (http://paggard.com/projects/doc.generator/) but there are some major issues which are not being fixed. Also users complain about RTF files (Word shows a warning message).

I am aware only of phpdocx. Are there other solutions around, is phpdocx a good one?

Thanks you for any ideas!

Comment: [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

Comment: Docxtemplater : https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater

Comment: Thank you, I will evaluate this, too.